# program to read a char array in c

Tags: c

I am quite new with C.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    char* c=argv[1];
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(c);i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a program to print every character of a word.

When I try with test: It displays
t
e
s
t
When I try with testtesttest: It displays:
t
e
s
t

I don't understand why, can you tell me why please?

Comment: sizeof(c) gives the size of a char* and not the length of the string

Comment: sizeof(c) returns the size of a pointer on your machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems: Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to. If you want the length of a string you should use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

The second problem is what will happen if there are no arguments to your program. Then `argv[1]` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` operator returns the size of the type of operand. `c` is of type `char *`, therefore `sizeof(c)`  will return the size of `char *` instead of the string.  You should use `strlen(c)`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(c)` is the memory size used by `c`, which is a `char*`, that is, a pointer on a `char`. This type takes 4 bytes of memory, hence the `t e s t` (4 chars). What you want is `strlen`, which gives you the length of a string.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    char* c=argv[1];
    int length = strlen(c);
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should also test that your program gets at least one argument. `argc` is the length of `argv`, so you need to ensure that `argc > 1`.